# How to take a screenshot of an app camera surfaceview and image overlay programatically without rooting?

Tags: java, android

I used a surface view and an image overlay on top of the surface view( background). I would like to use a button to take a snapshot of the screen without rooting the device. However when I take a take screenshot using the button, it captures only the foreground overlay, not the entire screen i.e background surface view image and the foreground image overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code and we can't analyze described behavior.
You can use android-beryl library's code to accomplish print screen functionality.

Entire code snippet is listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-beryl/source/browse/beryl/src/org/beryl/graphics/Screenshot.java).

I hope it helps.